# Why cannot define array variable in state of react class?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I've created a React class with state variable as array type.

```
export default class Demo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state ={
      test: []
    }
  }
```

Now, when I use `console.log(this.state.test)` in `render` function then it returns `object` type. I thought it is for the unique-key purpose when mapping.

But, what if I just want to define an array for push method?

Is there any other way to define the same? Please guide.

Comment: Have you tried pushing to it? It's definitely an array, but it's a key : value object. The objects property value is an array. `test` is not an array, it's just a key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that array are objects in javascipt.

```
typeof([]) //outputs object
```

To print the array in readable form, you can use JSON.stringify

`console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.test, null, 2))`

To set array in the state, you can use the setState method:

```
this.setState({test: [/* new array */]})
```

In react I really like to use the pre tag to show state while I'm developing.

Add this to render:

```
<pre>{JSON.stringify(this.state, null, 2)}</pre>
```

Comment: `typeof` is an operator, not a function, so the parens around `[]` are superfluous.